# How to stop dplyr from using wrong table name in ON clause when trying to pull data from SQL database?

Tags: r, dplyr, mariadb

I have several use cases where I construct a query to my MariaDB database using `dplyr` and then pull the final result down with collect().

Recently, these have all stopped working and producing the error message:

> Error in `collect()`:
> ! Failed to collect lazy table.
> Caused by error:
> ! Unknown column 'curriculum_standard.global_curriculum_standard_id' in 'on clause' [1054]

This is technically correct, there is no column with that name in that table in my database, but I am unsure why `dplyr` is generating a query that thinks there is in the first place.

The query I am building requires sequential joining of several tables, and it seems like whatever it is doing under the hood to translate the `by =`  section of each `inner join()` call is getting confused after the third or so join.

Here's what the `dplyr` code looks like:

```
##Imports
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
library(RMariaDB)

##Connecting to my DB
dashCon <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(),
                     default.file = path.expand("~/.my.cnf"),
                     group = "dashBI")


## dplyr query construction
## i know all these names are confusingly similar, but thats above my pay grade
q_curriculumCoverageTree = tbl(dashCon, "curriculum") %>% select(id, code, grade, deleted) %>%
  inner_join(
    tbl(dashCon, "curriculum_strand") %>% 
      select(id, curriculum), by = c("id" = "curriculum"), suffix = c("_curriculum", "_strand")
    ) %>%
  inner_join(
    tbl(dashCon, "curriculum_standard") %>%
      select(id, strand, code, description), by = c("id_strand" = "strand"), suffix = c("_curriculum", "_standard")
  ) %>%
  rename(id_standard = id) %>%
  left_join(
    tbl(dashCon, "curriculum_standard_global_curriculum_standard") %>%
      select(curriculum_standard_id, global_curriculum_standard_id), by = c("id_standard" = "curriculum_standard_id")
  ) %>%
  rename(gcs_id = global_curriculum_standard_id) %>%
  left_join(
    tbl(dashCon, "activity_curriculum_global_standards") %>%
      select(global_standard_id, activity_id), by = c("gcs_id" = "global_standard_id")
  )
```

And here is what `dplyr::show_query()` spits out:

```
SELECT
  `curriculum`.`id` AS `id_curriculum`,
  `curriculum`.`code` AS `code_curriculum`,
  `grade`,
  `deleted`,
  `curriculum_strand`.`id` AS `id_strand`,
  `curriculum_standard`.`id` AS `id_standard`,
  `curriculum_standard`.`code` AS `code_standard`,
  `description`,
  `global_curriculum_standard_id` AS `gcs_id`,
  `activity_id`
FROM `curriculum`
INNER JOIN `curriculum_strand`
  ON (`curriculum`.`id` = `curriculum_strand`.`curriculum`)
INNER JOIN `curriculum_standard`
  ON (`curriculum_strand`.`id` = `curriculum_standard`.`strand`)
LEFT JOIN `curriculum_standard_global_curriculum_standard`
  ON (`curriculum_standard`.`id` = `curriculum_standard_global_curriculum_standard`.`curriculum_standard_id`)
LEFT JOIN `activity_curriculum_global_standards`
  ON (`curriculum_standard`.`global_curriculum_standard_id` = `activity_curriculum_global_standards`.`global_standard_id`)
```

You can see in the last ON clause that for some reason it is assuming that the `global_curriculum_standard_id` column belongs to the `curriculum_standard` table from two joins ago, instead of the `curriculum_standard_global_curriculum_standard` from the previous join.

I thought that maybe the mixed use of `inner_join()` and `left_join()` might have been messing it up, but switching to all inner joins did not resolve the issue.

I also suspect this could be related to a package/R update, as this machine was recently updated and these queries all worked before.

I am unsure what version I was on previously as they're updated now, but current version info:

```
RStudio = RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium" 
R = 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt) -- "Innocent and Trusting"
tidyverse = 2.0.0 (dplyr1.1.0)
DBI = 1.1.3
RMariaDB = 1.2.2
```

Open to suggestions, either on how to make this approach work or how to overhaul it completely because I had no idea what I was doing and built it completely wrong in the first place.

Comment: Can you list your R version and the version numbers for each of the libraries you use from the output of `sessionInfo()` just in case it is a version issue?

Comment: Yup, definitely, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for closure, this issue appears to have been caused by dplyr adding a new functionality to their join functions that dbplyr had not been updated to support.

Now that both packages have been updated  (dplyr = 1.1.0, dbplyr = 2.3.1), my queries are behaving as expected.